# Can I use the Qpid C++ API to view the properties of an existing queue?

Tags: c++, linux, qpid

Essentially, I have a few C++ applications communicating over Qpid queues, one of which happens to be a last-value queue. I decided to throw an extra check into the applications using this last-value queue to ensure that the queue options line up with what I expect when connecting to the LVQ, but I can't find any way to do it. Using the Python qpid-stat tool to get queue information works (specifically I'm interested in the 'qpid.last_value_queue_key'), but I'm not well-versed enough in Python to follow how that information is obtained or to find an equivalent path through the C++ API. Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks!